# Runtime error '1004': Method of 'Value' of object 'Range' failed

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

I'm having issues pasting a formula that was built in the vba code to cells without getting the "Method of 'Value' of object 'Range' failed" error. I get the error when I try to place `p` using `Range("I" & i).Value = p`

I'm trying to loop through the rows of a column to paste a value. Also, I'm not sure that this is the cleanest way of setting this up.

```
Sub Odds()

Dim Year As String
Dim starting As String
Dim ending As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim p As String
Dim team As String


Year = InputBox("What year are you looking for?")

i = 3
x = 3

For x = 3 To 19

    For i = 3 To 258
    
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(x, 36).Value Then
        
            starting = Cells(x, 34).Value
            ending = Cells(x, 35).Value
            team = i
        
            p1 = "=IF(VLOOKUP($D"
            p2 = team
            p3 = ",'/Users/user/Desktop/NFL Betting/NFL_Data/Yearly_Odds/[Master_Odds.xlsm]"
            p4 = Year
            p5 = "'!$E$"
            p6 = starting
            p7 = ":$H$"
            p8 = ending
            p9 = ",4,FALSE)<0, VLOOKUP($D"
            p10 = team
            p11 = ",/Users/user/Desktop/NFL Betting/NFL_Data/Yearly_Odds/[Master_Odds.xlsm]"
            p12 = Year
            p13 = "'!$E$"
            p14 = starting
            p15 = ":$H$"
            p16 = ending
            p17 = ",3,FALSE)*-1,VLOOKUP($C"
            p18 = team
            p19 = ",/Users/user/Desktop/NFL Betting/NFL_Data/Yearly_Odds/[Master_Odds.xlsm]"
            p20 = Year
            p21 = "'!$M$"
            p22 = starting
            p23 = ":$H$"
            p24 = ending
            p25 = ",3,FALSE))"
            
            p = p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6 + p7 + p8 + p9 + p10 + p11 + p12 + p13 + p14 + p15 + p16 + p17 + p18 + p19 + p20 + p21 + p22 + p23 + p24 + p25
        
            Range("I" & i).Value = p
            
        End If
    
     i = i + 1
     
    Next i

x = x + 1

Next x

End Sub'
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `p19 = ",/Users/user/Desktop...` you're missing the opening single quote from the path.  If you're setting the formula then you should really use `Range("I" & i).Formula = p`

Comment: Add `Debug.Print p` just befor the line that errors, and examine the output in the Immediate Window.  Is it what you expect? Can you paste it into the Formula Br in Excel?

Comment: (Not solving your problem) In VBA, you should use `&` as string concatenation operator, not `+`

Comment: (Not solving your problem) you should declare an array(), then use `JOIN(array())` to combine the strings instead of P1 & P2  & P3 & ...